# nginx rewrite domain/service to domain

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a domain **http://test.test** . I need nginx rewrite rule that states: if you write *http://test.test/whatever/whatever* to go to **http://test.test**.

Comment: Did you try to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add:

```
 rewrite ^/.*/.*$ / last;
```

inside the server { } stanza for test.test.
This is assuming that 'whatever' can contain slashes.

The `last` keyword tells Nginx to restart its whole url matching process from the beginning but this time using the newly rewritten url.

More info on: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Comment: This is exactly the case. I added it and tested, but I get 404.

Comment: Can you tell me how to have multiple rewrite rules? For example:
rewrite ^/.*$ / ;
rewrite ^/.*/.*$ / last;

Comment: @Hristo you don't need both, I used ^/.*/.*$ in my answer because you explicitly asked for /whatever/whatever and I assumed you didn't want to redirect /whatever.
If you want to redirect anything below /* to /, just use rewrite ^/.*$ / last;

If you use multiple rewrite rules, replace last with break to avoid loops: with break nginx will stop evaluating location blocks and rewrite rules after applying the rewrite rule. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#break

Comment: I decide to use only one rule **rewrite ^/.*$ / last;** , but every time, no matter what I try I get error 500.

Comment: enable access_log and error_log and cut&paste the logs